# Why does my app stop working immediately after start (but without any error message)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I just started doing some simple mobile development using Android Studio.
The app is very simple. It should give positive or negative feedback when tapped or shaked (some kind of random decision support).
Unfortunally it stops working right after start (*"Unfortunally "Soll ich?" stopped."*) and I don't have a clue why.

I tried setting breakpoints in some lines, but they were never hit by debugger. I can't even find an error message.

Any ideas what might cause such behaviour?

Here are my files:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/background_material_dark"
    android:onClick="onLayoutClick">

    <TextSwitcher
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textSwitcher" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/should_i_question"
            android:id="@+id/textView_main"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="60sp"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text_default_material_dark"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />

    </TextSwitcher>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/hint0"
        android:id="@+id/textView_sub"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/hint_foreground_material_dark" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package de.hermannoffen.sollich;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextSwitcher;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements SensorEventListener {

    private static final int SHAKE_THRESHOLD = 600;

    private final String[] gAnswers;
    private long gLastUpdate = 0;
    private Random gRandom;
    private float gLast_x, gLast_y, gLast_z;
    private TextSwitcher gTextSwitcher;
    private SensorManager gSensorManager;
    private Sensor gAccelerometer;

    public MainActivity() {
        gAnswers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.answers);
        gRandom = new Random();
    }

    private void calcAnswer() {
        gTextSwitcher.setText(gAnswers[gRandom.nextInt(gAnswers.length)]);

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_sub);
        textView.setText(R.string.hintN);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gTextSwitcher = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.textSwitcher);
        gTextSwitcher.setInAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_in);
        gTextSwitcher.setOutAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_out);

        gSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        gAccelerometer = gSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        gSensorManager.registerListener(this, gAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        gSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        gSensorManager.registerListener(this, gAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
     public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

            float x = event.values[0];
            float y = event.values[1];
            float z = event.values[2];

            long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            if ((curTime - gLastUpdate) > 100) {
                long diffTime = (curTime - gLastUpdate);
                gLastUpdate = curTime;

                float speed = Math.abs(x + y + z - gLast_x - gLast_y - gLast_z)/ diffTime * 10000;

                if (speed > SHAKE_THRESHOLD) {
                    calcAnswer();
                }

                gLast_x = x;
                gLast_y = y;
                gLast_z = z;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    public void onLayoutClick(View view) {
        calcAnswer();
    }

}
```

**logcat**

```
01-24 14:55:07.381  24082-24092/de.hermannoffen.sollich I/art﹕ Debugger is active
01-24 14:55:07.570  24082-24082/de.hermannoffen.sollich I/System.out﹕ Debugger has connected
01-24 14:55:07.570  24082-24082/de.hermannoffen.sollich I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-24 14:55:07.770  24082-24082/de.hermannoffen.sollich I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-24 14:55:07.970  24082-24082/de.hermannoffen.sollich I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-24 14:55:08.171  24082-24082/de.hermannoffen.sollich I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-24 14:55:08.371  24082-24082/de.hermannoffen.sollich I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-24 14:55:08.571  24082-24082/de.hermannoffen.sollich I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-24 14:55:08.771  24082-24082/de.hermannoffen.sollich I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-24 14:55:08.972  24082-24082/de.hermannoffen.sollich I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-24 14:55:09.172  24082-24082/de.hermannoffen.sollich I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-24 14:55:09.372  24082-24082/de.hermannoffen.sollich I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-24 14:55:09.572  24082-24082/de.hermannoffen.sollich I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-24 14:55:09.772  24082-24082/de.hermannoffen.sollich I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
01-24 14:55:09.973  24082-24082/de.hermannoffen.sollich I/System.out﹕ debugger has settled (1376)
```

Comment: What does logcat say when you are not in debug? Nothing?

Comment: Look for a Fatal Exception in the Logcat when you run the app and see the error message that reports the app has stopped working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove This

```
public MainActivity() {
        gAnswers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.answers);
        gRandom = new Random();
    }
```

And move them to onCreate()

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gAnswers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.answers);
        gRandom = new Random();

        gTextSwitcher = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.textSwitcher);
        //.....
   }
```

Comment: That seems to solve my problem... I had to remove the `final` keyword but that's okay. Is there some explanation to this?

Comment: Activity is constructed during the onCreate process so in general we place the set up stuff inside onCreate()